# how to solve "IndexError: too many indices for array" by changing input image

Tags: python, computer-vision

I tried to run a project from GitHub which is https://github.com/nbei/Deep-Flow-Guided-Video-Inpainting.

I successfully run the code for demo files, but I got errors when I tried to run the code for the original data set. The error that I received is as follows.

[image]

I searched the internet and possible solutions offers changes in source code but since the original source code runs successfully for demo files so I should change input images.

The original paper didn't mention any preprocessing they performed. The input is two folders.

One for main frames and the second one is masks. I didn't have any problems with input frames.

The error mainly refers to masks. I printed simply the masks,

the result for masks with successful run is as follows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG8co.png)

and for failure case is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mTef.png)

So, my main question i:

1- What is the difference between two images?
2- Which preprocessing I should apply?

I really appreciated any help.

Comment: were you keeping the file names the same?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide error messages, not images of displayed error messages.

Comment: Why not ask this question at the github site for that program?

Comment: I asked same question in related github repository but no one replied me yet.